# Laravel Sql multiple Where Condition

Tags: mysql, laravel

```
      $items = property::orderBy('id', 'desc')
    ->whereProperty_categoryAndProperty_for_sale_or_rent('condo', 'rent')
    ->whereProperty_categoryAndProperty_for_sale_or_rent('apartment', 'rent')
    ->paginate('9');
```

Hello please help me about this multiple select category there and two category Condo and Apartment and type rent in laravel.
Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your query code's condition is

```
WHERE
property_category = 'condo' 
AND property_for_sale_or_rent.rent = 'rent' 
AND property_category = 'apartment' 
AND property_for_sale_or_rent.rent = 'rent'
```

so it will return no records.

You need to use where closure to get that:

```php
$items = property::orderBy('id', 'desc')
    ->whereProperty_for_sale_or_rent('rent')
    ->where(function($q) {
        $q->whereProperty_category('condo')
          ->orWhere('property_category', 'apartment');
    })
    ->paginate('9');
```